# Two prime numbers' relationship

Tags: prime-numbers

Let p<sub>1</sub> and p<sub>2</sub> be prime numbers and p<sub>1</sub> < p<sub>2</sub>. Proove that there is a natural number **n** for which:

p<sub>1</sub> + n(p<sub>2</sub> - p<sub>1</sub>) is prime **AND**

p<sub>2</sub> + n(p<sub>2</sub> - p<sub>1</sub>) is **not** prime

I've checked for n = 1, n = p<sub>1</sub> and all of the answers that sounded reasonable. I tried also subtracting p<sub>1</sub> + n(p<sub>2</sub> - p<sub>1</sub>) from p<sub>2</sub> + n(p<sub>2</sub> - p<sub>1</sub>) but I'm not getting anywhere. Any leads?

Comment: If you take $n=kp_2$ you can find a value $k$ for a prime in the first case by Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progression.

Comment: I can only find proof that there are infinitely many primes in Dirichlet's arithmetic progression. But that doesn't really help me, or does it?

Comment: You find a prime in the first sequence. The value of the second expression is automatically divisible by $p_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying $n=1$ is a good instinct - it would often work. The only trouble is that sometimes $2p_2-p_1$ is prime. But then you can try $n=2$ and only fail if $3p_2-2p_1$ is prime - and continue like so. Basically, if you examine the reason why it fails, you'll see that you can just increment $n$ until you have the desired property.

Observe that
$$p_2+n(p_2-p_1)=p_1+(n+1)(p_2-p_1).$$
In particular, if we define $s_n=p_1+n(p_2-p_1)$, then we are trying to show that there is some $n$ such that $s_n$ is prime and $s_{n+1}$ is not. Both $s_0$ and $s_1$ are prime. Clearly, some $s_n$ is not prime, since the sequence contains zeros mod any number coprime to $p_2-p_1$. Thus, consider the first $m$ such that $s_m$ that is not prime. Then, let $n=m-1$ and you're done.